# Why does choosing $\varepsilon$ to be arbitrarily small mean equality?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, riemann-sum

Suppose that $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ exists and there is a number A such that, for every   $\varepsilon> 0$ and $\delta > 0$ , there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$   with $||P||<\delta$ and the Riemann sum of $f$ over $P$ that satisfies the inequality $|\sigma -A|$ . Show that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=A$.

In the last part of this proof it follows that,

$|A-\int_a^bf(x)dx| \leq |A-\sigma|+|\sigma-\int_a^bf(x)dx| \leq 2\varepsilon$

Then it says we can choose $\varepsilon$ to be arbitrarily small so that $A=\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

If we choose $\varepsilon$ to be very small how does $A=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ follow?

Comment: Since you have $|A-\int_a^bf(x)dx| \leq 2 \epsilon$, we see that $A$ and $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ are arbitrarily close together (when we choose a sufficiently small $\epsilon$). For example, if you specified an $\epsilon = 0.0001$, you know $A$ and $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ are within $0.0002$ of each other. For our purposes, we say if two values can be made arbitrarily close to each other, they are equal.

Comment: "Then it says we can choose $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small so that $A=\int_a^bf(x)dx$." Are those really the exact words "it" uses? In fact I suspect there are a lot of details that you've copied incorrectly here. For example, your "inequality" is not an inequality and uses an undefined symbol $\sigma$.

Comment: You have a nonnegative real number that is less than or equal to all positive real numbers (that are sufficiently small). If it were equal to one of them, it would be greater than all smaller positive real numbers a contradiction. Thus it must be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $A$ and $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ are just numbers so this has nothing to do with integrals.

$$|a - b| \le \varepsilon \ \forall \varepsilon > 0 \to a=b$$

Pf:

Suppose on the contrary that $a \ne b$. We want to show that $\exists \varepsilon_0 > 0$ s.t. $|a-b| > \varepsilon_0$.

If $a \ne b$, then $|a - b| > 0$.

Choose $\varepsilon_0 = |a-b|$. ↯ QED

---

To help you better understand (at least this is how I understood it when I took basic real analysis), let's see the case where $a$ and $b$ aren't just numbers.

Recall definition of $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

> $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ wh $0 < |x-a| < \delta$

Here we don't (necessarily) have $f(x) \equiv L$ (meaning $f(x) = L \ \forall x$; hell we can have $f(x) \ne L \ \forall x$) because we don't have

'$|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon \ \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \forall x$'

We instead have '$\forall \varepsilon > 0, |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ *for some condition on $x$'*.

Now if we have $f(x) = b$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ then we have $f(x) \equiv L$ because:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ for some condition on $x$

$\to \forall \varepsilon > 0, |b - L| < \varepsilon$ for some condition on $x$

$\to \forall \varepsilon > 0, |b - L| < \varepsilon \ \forall x$

$\to b = L \ \forall x$

$\to f(x) = L \ \forall x$

$\to f(x) \equiv L$

---

To further elaborate on $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ being just a number by putting it in the context of $\varepsilon-\delta$, you can think of

$$|A - \int_a^b f(x) dx|$$

as analogous to

$$|L - \lim_{x \to a} f(x)|$$

After all, $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is a limit as well. As you said, $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ 'exists'.

---

Finally, do you remember the proof of uniqueness of limits of functions namely

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L, \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = M$$

?

You may be interested in:

[Prove that the limit of a function is unique.](https://mathchaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/prove-that-the-limit-of-a-function-is-unique/)

Comment: Your linking of this problem with limit definition does not appear to make much sense. The reason $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ does not imply that $f(x) =L$ necessarily is because the term $f(x) $ is variable and expression $f(x) - L$ is not a fixed/specific number. It has nothing to do with the fact that the inequality is valid for $x$ under some condition.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh When I took undergrad basic real analysis I was wondering the same. After all in both cases we have absolute values and $\varepsilon$. I was wondering how $f(x)$ wasn't equal to $L$ but it worked for real numbers. So yeah $f(x)$ is not always $L$ and may never be $L$ because such absolute value $\varepsilon$ statement is not unconditional because $f$ is not a fixed number, unlike $a$ because its value depends on $x$. PS I know Angelo086 personally so there may be something here that I didn't realise is specific to us.

Answer (score 5):

If you have $|R|\leq 2\varepsilon $ for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $|R|$ is a nonnegative real number that is less than any positive real number. It follows that $R=0$. If it weren't, and $|R|>0$, we get a contradiction by taking for instance $\varepsilon=|R|/4$.

Comment: Why do you write $|R|\leq 2\epsilon$ instead of $|R|<2\epsilon$? It is inadmissble that $|R|=\epsilon$, isn't it?

Comment: No. Why "inadmissible"?

Comment: Because then we would have $|R|=\epsilon>0$ and this implies that we could find a positive real number, e.g. $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, with $|R|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. This is a contradiction because we assumed that there is no positive real number which is smaller than $|R|$.

Comment: If $|R|=\epsilon>0$, then $|R|>2(\epsilon/4)$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I am trying to say, if $|R|=2\epsilon>0$ then we get a contradiction. So we can replace the $\leq$ by a $<$ because the case $|R|=2\epsilon$ can't occur.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not sure where you are trying to go. If a number is less than all positive reals, then it is zero. If a number is less than or equal all positive reals, then it is zero. Not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm may be the following explains my doubts better: It is superfluous to use $\leq$ because $\leq$ consists of the two cases $<$ **and** $=$. However, the case $=$ is inadmissible so we can reduce the notation and simply write $<$.

Comment: I'm struggling to see your point of view. Proving that something is less than or equal something else is easier than proving that something is strictly less. You say "two cases" as if $\leq$ is something bad, but often to prove $<$ one proves $\leq$ and $\ne$. Finally, I still don't see what you mean by "inadmissible" here.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a number $x \ge 0$, and I tell you that for any $ \epsilon >0$ we have $x < \epsilon$.

Then we **must** have $x=0$.

Suppose $x >0$ then take $\epsilon = {x \over 2}$ which gives
$0 < x \le {x \over 2}$, or $1 < {1 \over 2}$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side is <= epsilon for ALL SMALL EPSILONS ( not just some arbitrarily small epsilon). Clearly only 0 satisfies this.

Comment: "clearly" deserves a proof.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Then write one if that's how you feel.

Comment: no need, Martin Argerami has already written up an elementary proof of this fact

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Assume it is greater than some epsilon. Then it is greater than all sufficiently small epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\le |a-b| \le \epsilon $ forall $\epsilon >0$, then there is no $ \epsilon > 0$ such that $0 < \epsilon <|a-b|$.  But for all $x > 0$ there *does* exist some $\epsilon$ so that $0 <\epsilon < x $.

So $|a-b| \not > 0 $.

So $|a-b|=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally this boils down to (a) the [total ordering property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) of the real numbers, (b) the [Archimedian property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) of the real numbers, and (c) the fact that the absolute value [separates points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition).

Let 
$$x =\left|\int_a^b f(x) dx - A\right|.$$ 
We first observe that $x$ is a real number.

For any real number $x$, one and only one of the following properties must hold:

1. $x > 0$
2. $x = 0$
3. $x < 0$.

This follows from the fact that the real numbers are totally ordered.

We already know that $x$ is nonnegative, so that rules out the $x < 0$ (case 3.).

On the other hand, if $x>0$ (case 1.), then by the Archimedian property of the real numbers, we could find another number smaller than $x$ but still greater than zero. Whatever this number is that is supposedly smaller than $x$, we can just choose $\epsilon$ so that $2\epsilon$ is even smaller than this number. Then $x > 2\epsilon$ which contradicts the fact we already know which is that $x < 2\epsilon$. Therefore, since case (1.) leads to a contradiction, it cannot be true.

The only remaining possibility is the second case: $x=0$. Recalling the definition of $x$, this means:
$$\left|\int_a^b f(x) dx - A\right|=0.$$

Now, by the fact that the absolute value function separates points, we know that for any real number $y$, if $|y|=0$ then $y=0$. Hence
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx - A = 0,$$
and so 
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = A.$$